# Nested ScrollView can not scroll to bottom

Tags: react-native

I pull the scrollView to the bottom and it bounce back.

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View></View>
    ....
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}></ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The nested ScrollView needs the exact height.

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View></View>
    ....
    <ScrollView style={{height: 400}}></ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```